# Can You Get The Last Edited ID Without Using $mysqli->insert_id PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli, auto-increment

Is there a way to get that last Edited ID in a MySql table with php without using:

```
$mysqli->insert_id
```

The code I'm currently using  can not use $mysqli->insert_id. 
(at least to my limited knowledge )
My Sql execute is in a separate class and function.
I cant seem to find a way to make it work.

The code that pulls the data from the form:

```
    $PartyName = $_POST['txtPartyName'];
    $sDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['startDate']));
    $eDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['endDate']));
    //echo $_SESSION['ID']." ". $PartyName." ". $sDate." ".$eDate;        
    EditParty::NewParty($_SESSION['ID'], $PartyName, $sDate, $eDate);
    $_SESSION['PartyID'] = DataBase::LastInsert();
```

The function that makes the Sql statement and passes the needed values:

```
    public function NewParty($ID, $PartyName, $sDate, $eDate){

        $sql = "INSERT INTO parties (HostID, PartyName, sDate, eDate)
        VALUES ( '?' ,  '?' , '?' , '?' )";
        $BindVars =  array($ID, $PartyName, $sDate,$eDate);        
        $result = DataBase::RunSql($sql, $BindVars);
        $_SESSION['PartyID'] = DataBase::LastInsert();

        header('Location: /OnlineParty/PartyPlaning/EditPartyP.php');        
    }
```

And last the function for getting the last edited value

```
 public function LastInsert() {

        $mysqli = DataBase::ConDataBase();
        $result = $mysqli->insert_id;
        echo $result;
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: As long as `DateBase::ConDataBase()` returns the same connection that was used by `RunSql`, `insert_id` should work.

Comment: Do a `print_r($mysqli); exit();` right after calling `ConDatabase()`, see what it returns.

Comment: `$_SESSION['PartyID']` contains the last inserted ID.

Comment: Actually @Barmar that helped. I did start passing the connection though and then saved the variable in the $_SESSION which then I could call from anywhere.

Comment: @Mave that data was not being passed though DataBase::LastInsert();.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by passing the connection through to each function so that they were all using the same connection. saved the value from $mysqli->insert_id; in the $_SESSION for access anywhere.

```
public function RunSql($Sql, $BindVars) {

    $mysqli = DataBase::ConDataBase();
    $Sql = DataBase::ReturnData($Sql, $BindVars, $mysqli);
    $result = $mysqli->query($Sql);

    if (!$result) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli));
        exit();
    }
    $_SESSION['LastInsert'] = DataBase::LastInsert($mysqli);
    return $result;
}
```

Notice that the connection made in RunSql is the same used though out the whole process.

```
public function LastInsert($mysqli) {        
    $result = $mysqli->insert_id;
    //echo $result;
    return $result;
}
```